# Check for datatypes of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have an excel file which I'm importing as a pandas dataframe.

My dataframe `df`:

```
id    name    value
1      abc     22.3
2      asd     11.9
3      asw     2.4
```

I have a dictionary `d` in format:

```
{ 'name' : 'str',
  'value' : 'float64',
  'id' : 'int64'}
```

I want to check whether the data types of the columns in my dataframe is the same as defined in the dictionary.

Output can be just a string like, if all the columns have their respective data type,

```
print("Success")
else:
    print(" column id has different data type.Please check your file)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `dtypes`, convert to a dictionary and compare.

```
d1 = df.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict()

d1
{'id': 'int64', 'name': 'object', 'value': 'float64'}

d1 == {'name' : 'str', 'value' : 'float64', 'id' : 'int64'}
False
```

---

Unfortunately, `name` is shown to be an `object` column, not `str`, hence the `False`. I could recommend doing a quick iteration over your dict and changing all entries where `str` appears to `object` (this shouldn't hurt):

```
d2 = {k : 'object' if v == 'str' else v for k, v in d2.items()}

d2
{'id': 'int64', 'name': 'object', 'value': 'float64'}

d1 == d2
True
```

---

To check *which* column(s) are incorrect, the solution becomes a little more involved, but is still quite easy with a list comprehension.

```
[k for k in d1 if d1[k] != d2.get(k)] 
['name']
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yes str gets converted to object, is there any way to handle this issue? without using .astype(str)

Comment: @SRingne Unfortunately, not one I can think of. Numpy follows that same convention, and pandas seems to have followed suit. Only recommendation I can give is that you manually take your `dict` and convert `str` to `object` wherever it appears, before comparing with the data frame's dtype. That should do right?

Comment: @SRingne Showed you how to do that in an edit. Hope that's enough for you. Thankfully, converting str to object should be fine, because str is an object after all. I'd be more afraid of converting object to str, because columns of lists are also object columns (just not str columns).

Comment: True, can i also get to know which column has the wrong data type, if say the column value in my dataframe is int64, but in dictionary its defined as 'float64'

Comment: @SRingne Also pretty easily done. Added another edit. If you have further questions, you could open another post ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [5759]: s = df.dtypes == pd.Series(d)

In [5760]: ss = s[~s]

In [5761]: if ss.empty:
      ...:     print('sucess')
      ...: else:
      ...:     print ('columns %s have different data type' % ss.index.tolist())
      ...:
      ...:
columns ['name'] have different data type
```

---

Details

```
In [5763]: df
Out[5763]:
   id name  value
0   1  abc   22.3
1   2  asd   11.9
2   3  asw    2.4

In [5764]: d
Out[5764]: {'id': 'int64', 'name': 'str', 'value': 'float64'}
```

Comment: i'm getting the error in 1st step while comparing.
Value error Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: How should the behavior be if df contains column not present in d or d contains column not present in df?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `type` of first value in column to `str` and then compare:

```
d1 = {x: type(df[x].iat[0]).__name__ for x in df.columns}
print (d1)
{'name': 'str', 'id': 'int64', 'value': 'float64'}

print (d == d1)
True
```